# Equivalent of WifiEnterpriseConfig before Android OS 4.3

Tags: android, android-wifi

In my Android application, I let the user choose a Wifi connection for the device. Using `WifiConfiguration`, I am able to deal with WEP as well as WPA2-PSK networks. However, it appears WPA2-EAP requires one more field - username. Browsing the net, I came across a system class `WifiEnterpriseConfig` that seems promising. However, this API is available only for OS 4.3+. I am wondering if there is any other way to achieve saving EAP network config that would work for 4.1 and above. Any pointer is appreciated. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just copypaste source code of this class into your project, it should resolve your problem.

Comment: That is a good suggestion. However, I am not sure if the code is contained in just one class. Pulling out dependent classes may become a project in itself.

Comment: Except some constants from this class https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/keystore/java/android/security/Credentials.java you don't need to add additional dependent classes, just check source code. So you only need to fix references to those constants, it's not hard.